# Is there a way to add tracking information from our Fedex account to Magento via the API?

Tags: magento, fedex, ups

We don't originate the shipments, our suppliers ship on our behalf using our account number and a reference number. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an API method that will add a tracking # to an existing order. It works very well!!

Here is the Web Service details for the method:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.addTrack.html

You will need to pass in a shipmentIncrementId with your addTrack call so you will want to first call the create method.

If you can have your suppliers send you a Magento OrderID and Tracking # you should be able to call the .create and then .addTrack methods with that info to update your customer orders with the tracking information. Hope this helps!